# In Kotlin, can I have two random values with the second one omitting the first random number?

Tags: kotlin, random, numbers

Here is what I am trying to say:

```
val firstNumbers = (1..69).random()
val secondNumbers = (1..69).random()
```

I would like the `secondNumbers` to omit the random number picked in `firstNumbers`

Answer (score 4):

If you're just generating two numbers, what you could do is lower the upper bound for `secondNumbers` down to 68, then add 1 if it's greater than or equal to the first number. This will ensure an even distribution:

```kotlin
val firstNumber = (1..69).random()
var secondNumber = (1..68).random()
if (secondNumber >= firstNumber) {
    secondNumber += 1
}
```

For generating more than 2 numbers, the following code should work:

```kotlin
fun randoms(bound: Int, n: Int): List<Int> {
    val mappings = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()
    val ret = mutableListOf<Int>()
    for (i in 0 until n) {
        val num = (1..(bound - i)).random()
        ret.add(mappings.getOrDefault(num, num))
        mappings.put(num, mappings.getOrDefault(bound - i, bound - i))
    }
    return ret
}
```

It tries to emulate Fisher-Yates shuffling while only keeping track of swaps that happened, thus greatly reducing memory usage when `n` is much less than `bound`. If `n` is very close to `bound`, then the answer by @lukas.j is much cleaner to use and probably also faster.

It can be used like so:

```kotlin
randoms(69, 6) // might return [17, 36, 60, 48, 69, 21]
```

(I'd encourage people to double-check the uniformity and correctness of the algorithm, but it seems good to me)

Comment: This is what I'd do (if you're doing this a lot and want to avoid modifying the source lists each time). It's like "removing" the first number and letting the numbers above that move down a place to fill the gap. Now you're picking from 68, and then you move those higher numbers back to their original indices

Comment: Thanks so much.  I think this will put me on the right track.  I have a total of six different random numbers and none of them can should be the same.

Comment: Add to my what I said above: I am trying to print 5 random numbers from 1 to 69 with no duplets.

Comment: @JerryApplegarth This is the best answer to the question you asked, but not for the actual comment revealed in your comments. In general you should ask about the problem you actually want to solve, because simplified versions (2 vs 6) can have efficiencies which aren't available for the larger case.

Comment: @JerryApplegarth I've included an edit for multiple random numbers.

Answer (score 3):

random() is the wrong approach, rather use shuffled() and then take the first two elements from the list with take(). And it is a oneliner:

```
val (firstNumber, secondNumber) = (1..69).shuffled().take(2)

println(firstNumber)
println(secondNumber)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, while this is shorter, it suffers from the fact that `shuffled` collects the entire iterator to a list before shuffling it, which means it's slow and [runs out of heap space for larger upper bounds](https://pl.kotl.in/_hfQKGzGz).

Comment: That depends on the platform and which algorithm is used. When you look at JVM implementation and the Kotlin Native implementation then these are completely different algorithms. So you comment is correct for the JVM (only ?).

Comment: The Kotlin Native implementation [does the same thing](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/34e57a45f2d4283be572137b4b497414b8833ee7/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/collections/Collections.kt#L115) (collects to a list then shuffles)

Comment: No, it does not use the same shuffling algorithm. I doubt that one will run out of memory the same way as on the JVM. I do not know what you're trying to prove here. Shuffle() is perfectly fine for the OP's question. And I would have added your remark (of course mentioning you) to my answer, but this absoluteness of your comment is not appropriate. If it were, it would mean that shuffle() should be deprecated and removed at some point...

Comment: "If it were, it would mean that shuffle() should be deprecated and removed at some point..." No, because `shuffle` is designed for (and is good at) shuffling **lists**. Shuffling an extremely large range is beyond the intended use-case of `shuffle`. Also, `shuffle` returns a `List<T>`. If you have a range with 100 million elements and you shuffle it into a list, how can you expect to not use an extremely large amount of memory? After all, you end up with a list of 100 million elements.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to find one number in range 1..69, remove that number from the range and find the second one.

```kotlin
val first = (1..69).random()
val second = ((1..69) - first).random()
```

**Edit:** As per your comment, you want 6 different numbers within this range. You can do that like this.

```kotlin
val values = (1..69).toMutableList()
val newList = List(6) {
    values.random().also { values.remove(it) }
}
```

Comment: I like this idea: I wonder if I could do it six times? firstNumbers, secondNumbers, thirdNumbers, all the way through six numbers?

Comment: I have updated the answer to get 6 different numbers from the range. See if it fits your use case.